# How to support multiple external displays on Apple M1 silicon

Tags: apple-m1, xnu, external-display

I have a MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Chip used for the software development. I want to use two external displays to connect with my MacBook. But according to Apple documentation, Apple M1 chip only supports one external displays.

I have searched many materials, which told me that Apple M1 only has one monitor for the external display in addition to the one for the built-in display. So I guess M1 supports two displays? And I only need to use my MacBook with lid closed, which means I only need two displays.

So I wonder that with XNU kernel modification, can supporting two external displays on Apple M1 be achieved? I think there are two prerequisites. The one is that my MacBook can recognize two external displays simultaneously, and the other is that the monitor used for the built-in display can be used for an external display. I am looking forward to some precious suggestions. Thanks.

By the way, I have searched and found a solution, which uses DisplayLink and creates a software monitor for the external display. But I don't think it is a proper solution because of the high overhead and power cost. I hope a better solution.

Comment: The question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It would be on-topic on https://superuser.com or https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will ask on those platforms later.